# Excel Macro - Copy and Paste Values and Delete Original Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I will do my best to try and not sound confusing - so here goes:

I'm creating a spreadsheet that will hash SSN and DOB once the values are provided by a user. I have formulas that add last 4 ssn, first 4 dob, hashed dob and hashed SSN into their owns columns once the full SSN and DOB are provided. However, I want to remove the columns with the provided full SSN and DOB without losing the hashed DOB and SSN, including the first 4 DOB and last 4 SSN.

The spreadsheet format is:

`J               N              X                AQ
Hashed DOB   First 4 DOB     Last 4 SSN     Full SSN Hash`

The `Full date of Birth` and `Full SSN` columns are in columns `Q` and `R`.

Here is an old macro that I'm trying to work on to delete the original `Full date of Birth` and `Full SSN` values. I can't figure out how to get it to work on columns that are spread out rather than next to eachother.

```
Sub CopyAndDeleteSensData()

    Columns("E:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("J:K").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("E2").Select

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: The columns I wanted to keep as text are J, N, X, and AQ. The columns I want to delete are Q and R.

Comment: No - columns J, N, X, and AQ will never be blank if the full DOB and SSN is provided.

Comment: Correct. J,N,X, and AQ are all formulas and rely on Q & R to be filled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will:

1. Determine bottom row of data (`LRow`)
2. Copy/Paste as text for Col (`J, N, X, AQ`)
3. Delete Cols (`Q, R`) and shift cells to left

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrivateInfo()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ws
    Dim LRow As Long: LRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("J2:J" & LRow).Copy: .Range("J2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("N2:N" & LRow).Copy: .Range("N2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("X2:X" & LRow).Copy: .Range("X2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("AQ2:AQ" & LRow).Copy: .Range("AQ2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("Q:Q", "R:R").EntireColumn.Delete (xlToLeft)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

### Side Note:

Your question specifically asked for copy/paste solution, but a faster way to clear formulas and keep the values (marginally faster here, but in other situations much faster) would be to set a range equal to itself with `range.value` as such:

```
Dim Range1 As Range
Set Range1 = .Range("J2:J" & LRow)
Range1.Value = Range1.Value
```

Comment: I have one more column -- column Y that also has a formula in it that populates if Q and R is populated. Will the Macro work if I add the following? `.Range("Y2:Y" & LRow).Copy: .Range("Y2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Yes. Just add that **before** you delete the columns

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED TO FIX LAST LINE:

Your problem probably lies with the fact that you are deleting the columns, individually  (or a few at a time) and so the data is shifting after one delete and no longer lined up with your specified columns. Try deleting all columns at once, after all your inserts are done, like below.

```
Sub main()

    ' Delete columns A and C from "Sheet1"    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("a:a, c:c").EntireColumn.Delete


End Sub
```